# Compiling C code with R header files

Tags: c, r, header, compilation

I need R header files to compile something. I installed R on ubuntu via:

```
sudo apt-get r-base-dev
```

R works fine. But I can't find the  R headers such as Rmath.h. I get this error when I try to compile:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -I/usr/include -O3 -lRmath -lm -lpthread -o qcpg qcpg.c
In file included from qcpg.c:1:0:
qcpg.h:19:19: fatal error: Rmath.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [qcpg] Error 1
```

Any ideas??

Comment: The header files likely aren't in `/usr/include` (or are in a subdirectory). You may want to check `/usr/local/include`. When you locate the header files, update your include statement to `/r/header/dir` or `/usr/include/r/dir`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961247/r-h-and-rmath-h-in-native-c-program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also want to do

```
sudo apt-get install r-mathlib
```

which contains, among other things, the file `/usr/include/Rmath.h`.

Comment: Ouch, beat me by few seconds. +1

Comment: Sorry, next time you'll win :)

Comment: What about the R.h headers?